# WPF DataTemplate Textblock binding

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a listbox of Students and the datatemplate for list item. 
The DataTemplate has a text block named tb.
I want to set this textblock to be binded to Name property. 
How can I do it in xaml form outside? (Not from the datatemplate)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding l}"      ItemTemplate="{Binding DataTemplate_L}" Margin="12,70,0,0">

</ListBox>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking how you set the databinding for the textblock, that is currently in your DataTemplate? You can't set that databinding at the ListBox level; it has to be done in your DataTemplate.

In this case the DataTemplate will inherit the DataContext of each item in the list.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AnotherListItemProperty}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In other words - this DataTemplate is a template for each item in the list - and the DataContext will be each item in the list.

Comment: But the datatemplate should be generic... 
If I want to use this datatemplate in another place with another binding I cant...

Comment: Typically, you'd use a data template to define a template for a specific data type, model or view model. In your case, if you're wanting to reuse the datatemplate with a different data type, then there must be some common structure to your layout within that data template - which is why you wish to reuse it. Create a view model for that datatemplate that defines that structure, and bind it to that. This would give you the ability in your parent view model to set that text by creating a new instance of the templates view model, and transforming your data into it.